# Oracle check across multiple columns and return the first not 0.00

Tags: oracle, plsql, decode

I have three columns in my result set;

```
o.id    o.value_one    o.value_two    o.value_three
----    -----------    -----------    -------------
1       1.00           0.00           0.00
2       1.00           1.00           0.00
3       1.00           1.00           1.00
4       0.00           1.00           1.00
5       0.00           0.00           1.00
6       0.00           0.00           0.00
```

I want to compare all three value columns and return the value of the column where it is not 0.00.

So I would return;

```
o.id    o.new_value
----    -----------
1       1.00       
2       1.00       
3       1.00       
4       1.00       
5       1.00
```

Thanks for any help!
Chris

Comment: It won't return 1 for `id=6` - none of three columns values is other than 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry that is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of [NULLIF](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions.php#nullif) and [COALESCE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions.php#coalesce):

```
SELECT o.id, COALESCE(NULLIF(o.value_one, 0.0), 
                      NULLIF(o.value_two, 0.0), 
                      NULLIF(o.value_three, 0.0)) AS new_value 
FROM Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       decode(value_one, 0, 
                        decode(value_two, 0 
                               decode(value_three, 0, 0, value_three),
                               value_two),
                         value_one) new_value
from ...
```

Works w/o all expressions evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider an expression involving [GREATEST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm#i77473), like:

`GREATEST(o.value_one, o.value_two, o.value_three)`